# SQLite, How can I select more efficiently on large tables?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

any of you knows how to make this selection faster or more efficient? The thing is that this selection takes more than hours to procesate on SQLite. I am using it with `sqlite3` on Python so there is a few limitations of commands.

```
 SELECT C.id, COUNT (L.linea_construccion) 
 FROM Linea L, Predio P, Comunas C 
 WHERE L.calidad_construccion = 1 AND C.id = P.comuna
      AND L.comuna = C.id AND P.avaluo_exento > C.avaluo_promedio 
 GROUP BY C.id
```

There are 3 tables on a database, the table `Linea` has 9MM rows, the table `Predio` has 7MM and the table `Comunas` has 250 aprox.

The format of the tables is:

`Predio`. (`id INT`, `comuna INT`, `avaluo_exento INT`)

`Linea`. (`id INT`, `comuna INT`, `calidad_construccion INT`, `linea_construccion INT`)

`Comuna`. ( `id INT`, `avaluo_promedio INT`)

Comment: I have to ask: do you have indexes on the columns you are using for the join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use `explicit join` for the best practice, instead using `implicit join` on `where` condition.

from the given schema of your tables, you can try the following

```
SELECT 
  C.id, 
  COUNT (L.linea_construccion) 
 FROM Linea L
 join Predio P
 on L.comuna = P.comuna

 join Comunas C 
 on L.comuna = C.comuna

 where L.calidad_construccion = 1
 AND P.avaluo_exento > C.avaluo_promedio 
 GROUP BY 
  C.id
```

Comment: @manuellela . . . Although the better way to write the query, this should not change the performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

First, rewrite the query using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
 SELECT C.id, COUNT(*) 
 FROM Linea L JOIN
      Comunas C
      ON L.comuna = C.id JOIN
      Predio P 
      ON C.id = P.comuna AND P.avaluo_exento > C.avaluo_promedio 
 WHERE L.calidad_construccion = 1 
 GROUP BY C.id ;
```

Start with the following indexes:

- `Linea(calidad_construccion, comuna)`
- `Comunas(id, avaluo_promedio)`  -- probably not necessary if "id" is the primary key
- `Predio(comuna, avaluo_exento)`

Depending on how many "communas" you have and how many are returned, you might be able to further optimize this query by eliminating the outer `GROUP BY`.